# Integration by parts on the $N$-dimensional torus

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, differential-geometry

**My problem.** Consider the $N$-dimensional torus $$\mathbb{T}^N = \mathbb{R}^N /(2\pi n \mathbb{Z})^N \simeq [-\pi n, \pi n)^N$$

and consider two function $v,w \in H^2(\mathbb{T}^N)$. I want to integrate by parts the term $$ \int_{\mathbb{T}^N} Dv Dw $$ to obtain something like $$ - \int_{\mathbb{T}^N} \Delta v w $$ but I don't know what to do with boundary terms in the integration-by-parts formula.

**What I tried.** One could identify $H^2(\mathbb{T}^N)$ with $H^2_{per}([-\pi n, \pi n)^N)$ and use the integration-by-parts formula, but in order to obtain the result above, I would need to choose an unfolding of the torus such that $w$ vanishes on the boundary of $[-\pi n+\alpha, \pi n+\alpha)^N$. Is that correct?

In order to do so $w$ would have to have compact support in $\mathbb{T}^N$, right?

Comment: What is the meaning of $Dv$ and $\int_{T^n} DvDw$? I suggest that you consider first the one-dimensional case. Nothing dangerous happens there.

Comment: By $Dv$ I mean the gradient $\nabla v$. How exactly does nothing dangerous happen in the one-dimensional case?

Comment: Well,
$$
 \int_{S^1} f^\prime(\theta) \tfrac{d\theta}{2\pi} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} f^\prime(\theta) \tfrac{d\theta}{2\pi} = \tfrac{1}{2\pi}(f(2\pi)-f(0)) = \cdots
$$

Comment: Think about $\mathbb{T}^n$ as a closed surface and derive the correct integration by parts formula using the product rule and the divergence theorem - the torus doesn't have a boundary!

Comment: @AnthonCarapetis Thank you! Yes, the torus is a compact manifold without boundary. But how do I derive the integration by parts formula? Where can I find the divergence theorem for surfaces without boundary? Or is this just a special case of the divergence theorem where $\partial \Omega = \emptyset?$ I.e. does it say: $\int_\Omega u_{x_i} dx = 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Green's first identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identity) says the following:

Given an "admissible" body $B\subset{\mathbb R}^N$ with boundary $\partial B$, and $C^2$-functions $v$, $w$ defined on a neighborhood of $B$ one has
$$\int\nolimits_B\nabla v\cdot\nabla w\ {\rm d}(x)=\int\nolimits_{\partial B}w\>{\partial v\over\partial n}\ {\rm d}\omega-\int\nolimits_B\Delta v\  w\ {\rm d}(x)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here $${\partial v\over\partial n}:=\nabla v\cdot n$$ denotes the derivative in the direction of the outward normal, and ${\rm d}\omega$ is the scalar area element.

Apply this to the $N$-cube $B:=[-n\pi,n\pi]^N$ and periodic functions $v$ and $w$. Then the surface integral on the RHS of $(1)$ will vanish, since the integrals over opposite facets of $B$ cancel, and all that remains is
$$\int\nolimits_{T^N}\nabla v\cdot\nabla w\ {\rm d}(x)=-\int\nolimits_{T^N}\Delta v\  w\ {\rm d}(x)\ .$$

Comment: @mjb: Please note that I had the signs wrong. It's correct now.